# Leasing tasks from pull queues in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pull-queue

Do pull queues guarantee that a task will be leased to no more than one worker at any given point in time?

Failed to find any explicit mention of this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the lease itself guarantees that (as long as the lease doesn't expire). From [Leasing tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/pull/leasing-pull-tasks#leasing-tasks):

> Leasing a task makes it unavailable for processing by another worker,
>   and it remains unavailable until the lease expires.